# How to extract only specific type values from delimited string using regex in java

Tags: regex, java-8

I have a string like below:

```
SOMETEXT(ABC, DEF, 5, 78.0, MNO)
```

I want to parse it using regex to get the `List<String>` of ABC, DEF and MNO. ie. I want to avoid numbers of any type and extract only text.

At large, I have a structure like below:

```
class Detail {
    String name;
    String type;
}

// Sample values of name = "test1" type = "SOMETEXT(ABC,5)"
// Sample values of name = "test2" type = "SOMETEXT(ABC,DEF,2.2)"
// Sample values of name = "test3" type = "SOMETEXT(ABC,DEF)"
```

From the `List<Detail>` I want to get `Map<String, List<String>>` where `list<String>` is extracted texts from type and key is `name`, in java 8 way using streams if possible.

Till now I had to get only first text from the string and i did that as below:

```
Map<String, List<String>> assignOperatorMap = details
    .stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(md -> md.getName(), mapping((Details m) ->
        m.getType().substring(m.getType().indexOf("(") + 1,
        m.getType().indexOf(")")).split("\\,")[0] , 
        Collectors.toList()
    )));
```

Above code gives me:
`{test1=[ABC], test2=[ABC], test3=[ABC]}` that is only first value.

Comment: where is your regex?

Comment: I'm unable to derive a regex. i'm not good at it.

Comment: www.regex101.com

Comment: I've obtained a regext ([A-Z])\\w+ which gives me SOMETEXT ABC  DEF MNO but I want to avoid SOMETEXT. I want to start from (

Comment: when you substitute don't use $1, start from $2,$3, just drop first matching group

Comment: I'm using m.find() to add them to a list. to skip first one, i'm call m.find() once before iterating in loop to skip it.

Comment: @Drako, how can i extend this regex to ignore some texts for example HOURS, MINUTES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<>();
details.add(new Detail("test1", "SOMETEXT(ABC,5)"));
details.add(new Detail("test2", "SOMETEXT(ABC,DEF,2.2)"));
details.add(new Detail("test3", "SOMETEXT(ABC,DEF)"));

Map<String, List<String>> assignOperatorMap = details.stream()
    .flatMap(d -> Arrays.stream(d.getType()
            .replaceAll("\\w+\\((.*)\\)", "$1")
            .split(","))
            .filter(s -> s.matches("[A-Za-z_]+"))
            .map(s -> new SimpleEntry<>(d.getName(), s)))
    .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, mapping(Entry::getValue, toList())));

System.out.println(assignOperatorMap); // {test2=[ABC, DEF], test3=[ABC, DEF], test1=[ABC]}
```

The idea is to first capture the string in between the parenthesis with: `.replaceAll("\\w+\\((.*)\\)", "$1")`, then split it by `,` and filter out what doesn't match `[A-Za-z_]+`.

There is also a trick of creating a bunch of `Entry<String, String>` (Name, Type), to avoid having to stream twice, since every `Detail` can now yield multiple type strings, we have to somehow *flatten* them into a `List<String>` (instead of a `List<String[]>`). (preferably that would be done with Java 9's `flatMapping` collector, but it's not here yet).

---

> how can i extend this regex to ignore some texts for example HOURS, MINUTES

You can create a `Set<String>` with the words you want to ignore, and filter based on that in a second `filter` call:

```
Set<String> ignore = new HashSet<>();
ignore.add("HOURS");
ignore.add("MINUTES");

...
.filter(s -> s.matches("[A-Za-z_]+"))
.filter(s -> !ignore.contains(s)) // <-- extra filter call
.map(s -> new SimpleEntry<>(d.getName(), s)))
...
```

Comment: Doesn't work with spaces. Try with "SOMETEXT(ABC, DFD)".

Comment: @PedroRodrigues I didn't add this since it seemed obvious. But you can tweak the patterns to match different input. e.g. use `.split("\\s*,\\s*")`

Comment: Works perfectly, great approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this if order doesn't matter:

```
final List<Detail> details = Arrays.asList(
    new Detail("test1", "SOMETEXT(ABC, DFD)"),
    new Detail("test2", "SOMETEXT(ABC,DEF,2.2)"),
    new Detail("test3", "SOMETEXT(ABC,DEF,GHF)")
);

final Map<String, List<String>> map = details
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Detail::getName,
        Collectors.mapping(
            detail -> {
                final String[] values = detail.getType().split("[,(). 0-9]+");
                return Arrays.copyOfRange(values, 1, values.length);
            },
            Collector.of(ArrayList::new,
                (list, array) -> list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array)),
                    (source, target) -> {
                        source.addAll(target);
                        return source;
                    }
                )
            )
        ));

System.out.println(map);
// Output: {test2=[ABC, DEF], test3=[ABC, DEF, GHF], test1=[ABC, DFD]}
```

Comment: OP said want to avoid numbers